# Need to call AngularJS function on every ajax request

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-http-interceptors

I need to call one of my AngularJS function on every Ajax request that my application makes and I want to do it AngularJS Way (not a classic JS/JQuery Way)

Here is my code :

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', '$q',  function($location, $q) {
        return {
            'request': function(request) {
                // My angularJS Function goes here.
                return request;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);
}])
```

but it's not working some how.

No Error - No output on console. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', '$q',  function($location, $q) {
             var requestPromise = {
                  request: function(request) {
                       // My angularJS Function goes here.
                       return request;
                  },
                  responseError: function(response) {
                       return $q.reject(response);
                  }
             };
             return requestPromise;
        }]);
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Found duplicate $httpProvider.interceptors causing this issue. Fixed, now it's working fine.